# Remove readonly in Compact Framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework

What is the preferred way to remove the readonly attribute of a file in Compact Framework as we don't have a File::SetAttributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the OpenNetCF [Smart Device Framework](http://opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx), which has a FileHelper class that implements the [SetAttributes](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/5d3558e3-3631-f4a4-57d7-71fdd3da1bdd.htm) function.

Or if you don't want to go that route, you could PInvoke the native [SetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891925.aspx) method.

Answer (score 9):

This also works:

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
FileAttributes attributes = fileInfo.Attributes;

if ((attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
{
    // set the attributes to nonreadonly
    fileInfo.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
}
```