# Clearing the ReadOnly Flag in Windows Mobile 6 Professional

Tags: c#, windows, mobile

I am working on an application for WM6+ and am trying to overwrite an existing file:

```
File.Copy(src, dest, true);
```

But I get this error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: UnauthorizedAccessException
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
at System.IO.File.InternalCopy()
at System.IO.File.Copy()
```

So then I tried to change the File Attributes on the destination file to be able to overwrite it:

```
System.IO.File.SetAttributes(dest, FileAttributes.Normal);
```

But I then get this when I try to compile:

```
Error   1   'System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for 'SetAttributes'  L:\Admin\Applications_Source_Code\CommonTime_AEP_Config_Source\AEP_WM6 - Production Code\AEP_WM6\Form1.cs   133 26  AEP_WM6
```

Why does SetAttributes not exist?!

This is the file I am trying to overwrite (not a system file, just showing in case the path is relevant):

```
@"\Program Files\Common Files\Trimble\GeoData\PFToolkit.csw"
```

This seems to have done the trick (thanks to TheGreatCO's comment) pointing me here: [Remove readonly in Compact Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086939/remove-readonly-in-compact-framework)

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(dest); 
FileAttributes attributes = fileInfo.Attributes; if ((attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly) 
{ 
    // set the attributes to nonreadonly 
    fileInfo.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly; 
}
```

Comment: I dont know if it is the same but I DO know that on Windows Phone 8 you have to use the isolated storage library. You can't simply just save to the phone because you're not authorized to access certain sections of the drive. The isolated storage library keeps your stuff local and safe.

Comment: @AMR Windows Mobile 6 was about as secure as Windows 98.

Comment: I suggest you look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086939/remove-readonly-in-compact-framework It seems to be the same as yours.  The problem is .NET 3.5 Compact does not have File::SetAttributes.

Comment: Thanks @TheGreatCO the post you pointed me to did the trick! I added the link and solution to my original question

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks for the edit and info @JohnSaunders

Answer (score 0):

This problem's solution for using OpenNETCF framework. For example;

```
OpenNETCF.IO.FileHelper.SetAttributes("filePath is here", FileAttributes.Normal);
```